# Child not added, when check index it shows -1

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am not sure why i addedChild but when i check it's index it still shows -1.

What i am trying to do is:

1.)Loop a URLRequest and load bitmap pictures.

2.)Put them in individual _contentHolder

3.)Put everything in a viewport

4.)Check the index of the image when its clicked

5.)Display just the picture that is clicked(With a black background) (Picture viewer)

6.)When the picture or background is clicked again, it closes the "picture viewer"(The single picture with black background), and just display the list from before.

At the moment i can upload the pictures in a loop, then add them into a viewport, but i can not managed to get the index of the image and reload it.

Thanks for your time!

Code:

```
public var _contentHolder:Sprite = new Sprite;
public var _contentHolder1:Sprite;
public var loadedArray:Array = new Array;
public var blackBox:Sprite = new Sprite();
private var somedata:Array;
protected var Holder:Listing9 = new Listing9;
public var viewport:Viewport = new Viewport();
public var scroller:TouchScroller = new TouchScroller();

var my_url:Array = somedata;

function loadImage():void
{
    somedata = SearchVectorTest.lists;

    for (var i:int = 5; i < somedata.length; i++)
    {
        if (somedata[i])
        {
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.rentaid.info/rent/" + somedata[i]));
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
        }
    }
}

function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    loadedArray.push(e.currentTarget.loader.content as Bitmap);

    for (var i:int = 0; i < loadedArray.length; i++)
    {
        var currentY1:int = 200;
        e.currentTarget.loader.content.height = 200;
        e.currentTarget.loader.content.y += currentY1;
        currentY1 += e.currentTarget.loader.content.height + 300;
        _contentHolder.mouseChildren = false; // ignore children mouseEvents
        _contentHolder.mouseEnabled = true; // enable mouse on the object - normally set to true by default
        _contentHolder.useHandCursor = true; // add hand cursor on mouse over
        _contentHolder.buttonMode = true;

        _contentHolder.addChild(loadedArray[i]);

    }

    var viewport:Viewport = new Viewport();

    viewport.y = 0;

    viewport.addChild(_contentHolder);

    var scroller:TouchScroller = new TouchScroller();
    scroller.width = 300;
    scroller.height = 265;
    scroller.x = 10;
    scroller.y = 100;
    scroller.viewport = viewport;
    addChild(scroller);

    _contentHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscene);
}

loadImage();

public function gotoscene(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var searchString = loadedArray;
    var index:Number;

    index = searchString.indexOf(e.target);
    trace(index);
    trace(_contentHolder);
    trace(_contentHolder.parent);

    blackBox.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    blackBox.graphics.drawRect(-1, -1, stage.width, stage.height);
    blackBox.alpha = 0.7;
    addChild(blackBox);
    Holder.height = 300;
    Holder.width = stage.width;
    Holder.x = 0;
    Holder.y = 100;
    trace(blackBox);
    trace(blackBox.parent);
    addChild(Holder);

}

function gotoscene1(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    removeChild(Holder);
    removeChild(blackBox);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The indexOf you are using strict equality (===). e.target is of type Sprite and your array is filled with Bitmaps.
The strict equality will fail because the objects are not of the same type.

You need to use items of the same type to make the comparison succeed.

Comment: Ahh ok, i am wondering what else can i use except indexOf in order to keep them as the same type? Because i tried removing the Bitmap part and it still doesnt work, i am simply using loadedArray.push(e.target.content); but it is still -1

Comment: If you debug to the line
index = searchString.indexOf(e.target);
What are the types of the items in searchString and the type of e.target?

Comment: I just tried tracing searchString and tracing e.target, and it says searchString is object,Bitmap and e.target is object Sprite.......but i already removed the part that push e.target as bitmap tho